# AM Nav - startFromId - how?

Tags: plugins, navigation

Anyone know how to utilise the **getActivePageIdForLevel** function that AM Nav (https://github.com/am-impact/amnav) now has? Would really like to be able to have a secondary menu on a page which just has the navigation items that are for that current section. Can't see how to use it in the Docs though?

Comment: Hi Mark, have you tried getting in touch with the plugin author directly?

Comment: I've opened an issue on GitHub yes. Just thought I'd ask on here though in case anyone had ever used it before. Just now wondering how do you all go about creating site navigations for clients then that they can add entries to and update themselves or does nobody tend to give that power to clients?

Comment: I haven't used AM Nav myself and can't answer your question. Personally, I usually create a Structure section called "Navigation", with an Entry field for the link: http://cly.mmikkel.no/image/2O361P2L0w3S. Note that the "Navigation item:" part of the entries is auto prefixed using a "Label" field (the latter is the one I display on the frontend): http://cly.mmikkel.no/image/0q1B460u2D3k. The reason I add the prefix is just because then the nav items stand out from other "actual" entries. Finally I usually use the [{% nav %}](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/nav) tag to output.

Comment: Hi mmikel. Many thanks for the insight. Just wondering though. With the `{% nav %}` tag is it possible to get it to output a secondary navigation such that if you are on a subpage then the secondary navigation would just show everything for that section? Really hoping so?